# Should I query the database as user types or left the job to Bloodhund?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js, bloodhound

I'm using Typeahead.js to search products in our webapp.
We are currently using Bloodhound to do a remote fetch of suggestions.
In the server, I'm doing a database query using the string entered by the user.
But I suspect, that the idea of using Bloodhound is not to do that in the server...

My JS code is as follow:

```
var products = new Bloodhound({
                    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
                    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
                    limit: 205,
                    prefetch: 'Product/GetData?q=&ft=true',
                    remote: 'Product/GetData?q=%QUERY'
                });

                products.initialize();

                $('#the-basics  .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
                    name: 'products',
                    displayKey: 'name',
                    source: products.ttAdapter(),
                    minLength: 3,
                    templates: {
                        empty: [
                            '<div class="empty-message">', 
                            'No products for current query',
                            '</div>'
                        ].join('\n'),
                        suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{name}}</strong></p>')
                    }
                });
```

I have a Action in my Product controller to retrieve a list of products... so that on Prefetch I'm only returning the ACTIVE products... but then is you write something in the text box the remote option is triggered and returns all that matches the query.

My GetData action code:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetData(string q, bool ft = false)
{
    if (ft == true)
    {
       var fetchTag = db.Products.AsNoTracking()
           .Where(x => x.Active == true && x.idTenant == CurrentTenantID)
           .OrderByDescending(x => x.Active).ThenBy(x => x.Nombre)
           .Take(20)
           .Select(x => new TagSys() { tag = x.idCaballo, name = x.Nombre }).ToList();

        return Json(fetchTag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var fetchTag = db.Products.AsNoTracking()
            .Where(x => x.idTenant == CurrentTenantID && x.Nombre.StartsWith(q.ToLower()))
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Active).ThenBy(x => x.Nombre)
            .Take(20)
            .Select(x => new TagSys() { tag = x.idCaballo, name = x.Nombre }).ToList();

        return Json(fetchTag, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   
    }

}
```

**First issue:[Solved]** despite the fact that the query entered matched values in the Prefetch data, it returns values from the remote data. Why is this? **ANSWER**: *The bloodhound tokenizer need a datum field/property as parameter. "value" was not a property in my datum... changing to "name" in my caso solved the issue.*

**Second:** Should I query the database using the query value entered by user in the remote method, or should I return a big list and let Bloodhound do the work?

**Third:[solved]** I used the `minLength: 3` option, hoping that it will start suggesting/searching just after 3 chars in the input, but I'm seeing that it is triggered after the first key pressed. ANSWER: this option is top level, not dataset related, so in my code, I replaced the `null` parameter in typeahead init with `{ minLength: 3}` and it worked.

Comment: If you comment out the "remote" definition, does "prefetch" actually work?

Comment: Weird, commenting the remote line... the component did the prefetch invocation, but once I type something that should be in the prefetch data, it says that nothing was found. I just realized another issue, updated question.

Comment: Well, the issue with the Prefetch was solved. The "value" passed in the Bloodhound init, should be the one of the properties of the datum. Changing it to "name" in my case, makes it work.

Comment: Regarding your second question, you probably know the answer already ;) If its a relatively small dataset, prefetch the results as the response time for the suggestions will be less. If it's a big dataset then use remote, though there will be an added delay to retrieve the results. Hence no surprises in the comparison of the two  options.